# Why weren't the Noghri used more during the Yuuzhan Vong War?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

By all accounts, the [**Noghri**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Noghri) - and specifically the [Death Commandos](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Noghri_Death_Commando) - were some of the galaxy's most deadly hand-to-hand combatants. When the [Yuuzhan Vong War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong_War) started, [Leia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leia_Organa_Solo) had reduced her Noghri entourage to only two bodyguards, but this was for political reasons.

Given the deadliness of the [Yuuzhan Vong](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong) and the threat that they represented to the galaxy, one has to wonder why the Noghri weren't brought back into the fold as commandos. Surely any political or diplomatic mistrust would pale in comparison to the annihilation of all non-Vong life in the known galaxy... right?

**Why weren't the Noghri used more during the Yuuzhan Vong War, or (if they were), what significant missions did the Noghri undertake against the Vong?**

Please keep in mind that this question is NOT about the Noghri guarding Leia, but rather the thousands of other Noghri who had been relocated to Wayland by the time the Vong invaded - all of whom were still sworn to serve the "Lady Vader" and protect her family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the New Jedi Order book, *Dark Tide II: Ruin*, by Michael A. Stackpole, Jacen Solo and Corran Horn undertake a mission with 6 Noghri commandos to the planet Garqi in a strike operation against the Vong. This is only reference outside of Leia's bodyguard to Nohgri I could really find. However, in the novel "Planet of Twilight", there is mention of an incident with the Barabel ambassador, after which Leia was pressured to reduce the Noghri presence. The following passage is Leia thinking about it:

> Several years had passed since, in the face of mounting pressure from
>   the Council, Leia had eliminated her bodyguard of Noghri
>   hunter-killers.
>
> Leia understood it; even before the unfortunate incident of the
>   Barabel ambassador, there were those who said it ill behooved her to
>   wield a weapon that had been Palpatine's. Bringing them on this
>   mission had been a terrible risk.

For more information on the Noghri: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Noghri (I realize this may not quite qualify as a source since it is a wikia.

For the specifics of the Battle of Garqi (in case you just want the run down instead of reading the whole book.): http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Garqi